# How to alert time process using jQuery in the proper way?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to show the time of process of my php code using jQuery

My php code example :

```
<?php 
   //some queries to database
?>
```

Here's my jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "action.php",
        data: {
            action: "simpanFitur", fitur: $('#feature :selected').val()
        },
        success: function(){
            var stop = new Date().getTime()-start;
            alert("Tersimpan.\n Lama proses : " + stop);
        },
        error: function(cek){
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
```

The alert show this :

[image]

Can somebody help me how to make it more readable ? Because I dont know what value that showed on my alert. Thank you.

**I've modified my ajax request to be like this :**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "action.php",
        data: {
            action: "simpanFitur", fitur: $('#feature :selected').val()
        },
        success: function(time){
            alert("Tersimpan.\nLama proses : " + time);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
```

But the alert didn't show the `time` value.

[image]

Did I do something wrong ? Please tell me.

**This is the latest alert :**

[image]

How to make it more simple ?

Comment: How about https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_time_label ?

Comment: The time difference is in milliseconds. Divide by 1000 to get in seconds. In your case 488.165 seconds

Comment: Also you can find usefull information in Chrome/Firefox developers tools [look here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/resource-loading) Why do you need to track time in this way ?

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam could you please tell me how to make it in seconds ? I've try to divide it with 1000, but still give me as on the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You could always return in the `action.php` response a key called `time` containing the total time the request took, then you can handle this in your success section and display as you wish.

You could generate the value of `time` with:

```
$time = microtime(true) - $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"];
```

Comment: How to make it in seconds or minutes ?

Comment: `$seconds = $time / 1000000;`

Comment: Hey, where should I put `$time = microtime(true) - $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"];` ? On the top of my php ?

Comment: My alert show this value `2.43902206421E-9`
I'm getting more confuse about this